# Can't connect Spark worker in a cloud vm instance to Spark master mode on local machine

Tags: azure, docker, apache-spark, cloud

I have a Spark worker on a virtual machine in Azure and I am trying to connect to the master node receding in a container on my local machine. I have exposed the ports for the master node, and both the worker and the master node seem to be working fine.

```
version: "3.6"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyterlab:3.2.0-spark-3.5.0
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 4040:4040
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-master:
    image: spark-master
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-worker-1:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-1*
    # environment:
    #   - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
    #   - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
```

This is my Docker Compose file for the spark master and the local worker.

```
sudo docker run -d     -e SPARK_MASTER_HOST=<my_ip_address>     -e SPARK_MASTER_PORT=8090     spark-worker
```

This is the command used to start the cloud vm. I have created a Docker container in the vm since it was a bit easier.

I have changed all the inbound and outbound rules on my vm and on my local computer, so I don't think the issue is with the firewall. But when I try to ping my local machine on my VM using telnet, it gave a request timed out error.